# ASP.NET Inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, inheritance

I have 2 projects that are asp.net 2008 websites.

The file structure is as so:

```
P_Project
P_Project/index.aspx.cs
P_Project/App_Code/PageBase.cs

P_Project/Q_Project/App_Code/PageBase.cs
```

In my index.aspx page, I call P_Project's PageBase.isPLoggedIn() but how do I get access to Q_Project's PageBase.isQLoggedIn() from my index.aspx.cs page?

Comment: one's in P_Project namespace and the other is in Q_Project namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are separate web projects, you won't be able to do it unless you have a reference to the Q_Project in the P_Project (and vise versa)

This is probably a bad idea.

Instead, you should have a class library (maybe one for each of P_Project and Q_Project) and refer to each of them in your web project.

You would then be able to refer to it via Q_Project.PageBase.isQLoggedIn().

Comment: But whether it will work is going to depend very much on the implementation of isQLoggedIn(). If you are using the Membership provider that comes with ASP.NET, you'll need to make sure they have the same application name, and edit the Web.config to make sure the two applications can decrypt each others authentication tokens. Check here ([link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/10/432851.aspx)) for example.

Answer (score 0):

1- Did you referenced Q_Project to P_Project? If not add Q_Project to P_Project as reference.

2- Make sure PageBase.isQLoggedIn() is a public method.

3- If you don't create an instance of PageBase class then make sure PageBase.isQLoggedIn() is public and static method.